# subclassing and data contracts

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm playing with the following code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserAccountService
{
    [OperationContract]
    UserAccountResponse CreateNewUserAccount(UserAccountRequest userAccountRequest);
}

public abstract class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccountResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public int NewUserId { get; set; }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Do I need to add the DataContract attribute to both the abstract class and the subclass?
2. If the abstract class does not need the DataContract attribute, can I add the DataMember attribure to its properties?

Comment: When I have questions like these, with WCF, I like to use a tool called soapui http://www.soapui.org/ to make requests and see the result. If you get it wrong, you will see the missing XML in the request and response.  
I start with the least amount of attributes and add them as I need them.
I use the free version and it has become a must have tool for me in any SOAP-related development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want items in the base class to be serialized, then you must apply DataContract to the base class and apply DataMember to those items that are to be serialized in the base class. However, if you do not want anything in the base class to be serialized, then you shouldn't need to specify DataContract on the base class.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx):

"When you apply the DataContractAttribute to a base class, the derived types do not inherit the attribute or the behavior. However, if a derived type has a data contract, the data members of the base class are serialized. However, you must apply the DataMemberAttribute to new members in a derived class to make them serializable."

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to use [DataContract] on both BaseResponse and UserAccountResponse. You will also have to use the [KnownType] attribute for every subclass as shown below.

```
[KnownType(typeof(UserAccountResponse))]
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseResponse
{
...
}
```